# QMSQL : Cannot mix incompatible Qt library (version 0x50b03) with this library (version 0x50c05)

Tags: mysql, linux, qt, debian, qtsql

I'm trying to use a MySQL database in a QT application. For this I needed to build the MySQL manually and nothing went as planned at all.

Using:
Qt 5.12.5
g++ 8.3.0
Make 4.2.1
MySQL 15.1
Debian 10.1

I first tried to follow this guide: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/sql-driver.html but qmake wouldn't detect MySQL headers.

After searching the internet I found out somebody managed to work things out by building directly the driver.

I went in ~/Qt/5.12.5/Src/qtbase/src/plugins/sqldrivers/mysql and ran :

```
qmake qmake "INCLUDEPATH+=/usr/include" "LIBS+=-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -lmysqlclient_r"
```

It didn't work :

> Project ERROR: Library 'mysql' is not defined.

After some googling, I changed the mysql.pro file to this one:

```
TARGET = qsqlmysql

HEADERS += $$PWD/qsql_mysql_p.h
SOURCES += $$PWD/qsql_mysql.cpp $$PWD/main.cpp

OTHER_FILES += mysql.json

PLUGIN_CLASS_NAME = QMYSQLDriverPlugin
include(../qsqldriverbase.pri)
```

It worked, for now. Next step, running make ! Guess what? Didn't work either.

> /usr/include/c++/8/cstdlib:75:15: fatal error: stdlib.h: No such file or directory

ran qmake again without "INCLUDEPATH [...]", now I was missing mysql.h. I added manually the path to it to the Makefile. It worked.

I tried running my QT app again, still no MySQL driver.

Turned out the newly built driver was not copied in the right directory with the other ones. So I copied in Qt/5.12.5/gcc_64/plugins/sqldrivers.

Now it seems my plugin is indeed recognized by Qt but it just crashes with this error :

> Cannot mix incompatible Qt library (version 0x50b03) with this library (version 0x50c05)

I don't know what to do next, can't find anything useful for this case on the internet...

Help, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out I had another version Qt installed on my system. I don't where it came from but this issue is now solved.